# Can we use FCM API KEY FOR GCM

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am new for GCM/FCM. My team created API Key for FCM but due to some internal issues we can not use FCM. May i know if I can use same API Key for GCM.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Server Keys generated for FCM could be used for old GCM projects.

However do note that the only way to generate a Server Key right now is by creating a Firebase Project in the Firebase console. From the [GCM docs](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/gcm#key):

> Starting from September 2016, you can create new server keys only in the Firebase Console using the [Cloud Messaging](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/settings/cloudmessaging) tab of the **Settings** panel. Existing projects that need to create a new server key can be imported in the [Firebase console](https://firebase.google.com/console/) without affecting their existing configuration.

Comment: Thanks a lot @AL.  Could you please let me know if we can send push notification to FCM by using GCM . I mean some application sent message to  GCM and then GCM sent it to FCM.

Comment: Hi Pandey. I'm a little confused. Do you mean if you could use your app to send to GCM clients for FCM?

Comment: Is the opposite also true? I mean, after migrating my server from GCM to FCM, can I continue using my old server key generated through the GCM console?

Comment: @JHH I think the key would still work, however, if it's a reeeaallly old server key, I would strongly suggest that you proceed to using the newer one.